# Binding с другой страницы

Tags: c#, uwp

Здравствуйте. Ввиду обстоятельств, пришлось реализовать MediaElement на странице App.xaml.

```html
<Application.Resources>
        <MediaElement x:Key="GlobalPlayer" AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" AutoPlay="True" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </Application.Resources>
```

Из MainPage.xaml.cs я легко получаю к нему доступ. Но есть ещё ProgressBar, который задаётся в MainPage.xaml

```html
                    <ProgressBar Visibility="Collapsed" Height="5" x:Name="PlayingProgressBar" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Maximum="{Binding Path=NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=App.Player}" Value="{Binding Path=Position.TotalSeconds, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=Player}" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,0,60,0" ShowPaused="True" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource MediaButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}" Foreground="{ThemeResource MediaButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Control"/>
```

Как правильно забиндить данные между страницами от этого MediaElement для ProgressBar?

**ОБновление**

Сам плеер.

```html
    <Application.Resources>
<MediaElement x:Key="GlobalPlayer" 
   Name="GlobalPlayer" AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" 
   AutoPlay="True" Visibility="Collapsed" />
</Application.Resources>
```

```html
Привязка к нему из любой страницы.

<ProgressBar x:Name="PlayingProgressBar" Height="10"
   VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
   ShowPaused="True" BorderBrush="{ThemeResource   MediaButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}"
   Maximum="{Binding NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalSeconds, Mode=OneWay, 
   Source={StaticResource GlobalPlayer}}" 
   Value="{Binding Position.TotalSeconds,    Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource GlobalPlayer}}"/>
```

Comment: Вы делаете неправильно. UI-элементы не нужно класть в ресурсы. Расскажите, какая ваша настоящая проблема.

Comment: Связать "глобальный" медиаэлемент, который указан в App.xaml с прогрессбаром, находящимся на странице MainPage.xaml.

Comment: Не-не, стойте. «Глобальным» UI-элемент сделать не получится, поскольку UI-элементы нельзя расшарить. Вопрос в том, какую проблему вы пытаетесь решить, положив MediaElement в ресурсы. Эту проблему нужно решать по-другому.